# Using JWT token as claim value

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My user journey starts with a customer JWT token passed in the url redirect to B2C. I use some claims from that token in the journey but also need the complete raw (string) token as input to a REST service. (The service needs to use that token to authenticate back to the original issuer to get some additional data). is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate your little more.  You said JWT token passed to B2C? Is that something you trying to send JWT token to B2C instead of getting that from B2C?

Comment: I am using a JWT token I create to initiate a B2C UserJourney. That part is working fine: the journey extracts some claims from my token and proceeds with the other steps. However, I need to add a step which calls a REST service. I would like to use the original token as a way to authenticate the call to the REST endpoint.